# Grouping display data from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table like such:

```
     Boxes     Items         Weight (kgs)
   ==================================
     101        CHICKEN       2 
     102        CHICKEN       3 
     104        CHICKEN       4 
     105        BEEF          3
```

Is it possible, in MySQL and PHP, to display this data in the following format for an HTML table?

```
Boxes                 Items
=====================================
101-104               9kgs of CHICKEN
105                   3kgs of BEEF
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` and get almost what you want, assuming that  all boxes with CHICKEN need to be totaled and not only the ones with consecutive numbers.

Comment: @PM77-1 GROUP_CONCAT doesn't do anything like this.

Comment: Is the text "kg" actually in the weight column?

Comment: @ShWiVeL No, not really. I just wrote it for clarity.

Comment: @Barmar - `GROUP_CONCAT` on Boxes will produce `101,102,103,104`. Then PHP will need to remove the middle. That's what *almost* mean. Kinda what `Sammitch` did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE COUNT(*)
        WHEN 1 THEN boxes
        ELSE CONCAT(MIN(boxes), '-', MAX(BOXES))
       END AS Boxes,
       CONCAT(SUM(Weight), 'kgs of ', items) AS Items
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Items
```

Comment: +1 - just note that this assumes you store your weight as a number (int, float, decimal) and not text with "kg" at the end, as it seems the OP has done.

Comment: Actually, MySQL will simply ignore everything after the number, so it will work with `1 kg`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT min(boxes),max(boxes),items,sum(weight) GROUP BY items
```

But you have a few problems, your table seems to contain text and not numbers, you'll need to fix that so functions like MIN, MAX, SUM, AVG work. Second, your box numbers are (or may be) non-contiguous, so you probably want to handle that separately. The logic of that is a bit more complicated. E.g. what if you have box 200 and 203 with chickens and 201 and 204 with beef, and 202,205 pork, if it says 200-203 is chicken, then it's wrong. Then again if you have many boxes the list will be large. That's half-way into user interface design land.

Good luck.

Comment: @Sammitch He asked about that in the sentence that begins "E.g. what if you have"

Answer (score 0):

```
    $query = " select group_concat(Boxes) as box,sum(weight) as weight , item 
             From your_table
             group by item";

 $result = $mysqli->query($query);

 echo "<table>
         <thead> 
          <th>Boxes</th>
          <th>Items</th>
        </thead>";
 while($row = $result->fetch_array())
 {
       echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>".$row["box"]."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$row["weight"]." kg  of ".$row["item"]."</td>";
       echo "</tr>"; 
 }
   echo "</table>";
```

Weight field should be a number

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Boxes), Item, SUM(Weight)
FROM Inventory
GROUP BY Item
```

Will give you:

```
Boxes          Items     Weight
=====================================
101,102,104    CHICKEN   9
105            BEEF      3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat(min(boxes), '-', max(boxes)) as boxes,
       concat(sum(weight), 'kgs of ', items) as items
  from tbl
 group by items
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07850/4/0